# Django Aggregation - Trying to return two values

Tags: python, django, django-models, aggregation

I am trying to get the username and text of their most recent post using an aggregation function.

I am trying the code below, but I don't get distinct values for the user name.

```
conversations = Chat.objects.values('user__username','body').annotate(Max('dateofpost'))
```

With the above it gives me all posts by that user, but what I am trying to get is the user name with the body text of the post that is the most recent one posted. Can anyone help?

I have been reading online, but can't find an explanation of what to do in this situation. I can see posts on calling the aggregate / values method again, but can't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can get it to work this way:

```
conversations_qs = Chat.objects.values('user__username').annotate(Max('dateofpost'))
conversation_dates = [conv['dateofpost__max'] for conv in conversations_qs]
conversations = Chat.objects.filter(dateofpost__in=conversation_dates)
```

Is there a better way to do it?